# RewriteRule messes with subdomain

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a subdomain called `login`, with a file `index.php` in that folder (the folder is located in my document root). An `.htaccess` file is also in the document root, with this as its contents:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.example.com/error
ErrorDocument 403 http://www.example.com/error
ErrorDocument 500 http://www.example.com/error
```

When I go to `http://login.example.com/`, I end up on the aforehand mentioned error page. However, if I navigate to `http://login.example.com/index.php` it all works fine. I am not very familiar with RegEX, but I do have a suspicion this is because of my `.htaccess` file, which should only be removing the `.php` at the end in URLs.

Any help greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**: I've fixed the problem by adding an `.htaccess` file in the folder `login` with this in it:

```
RewriteEngine Off
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Thanks for the help everyone! :-)

Comment: Probably you need `DocumentRoot index.php`

Comment: @RahilWazir shouldn't that be the default on apache though? Because it works just fine if I go to `http://www.example.com/`, there it just displays my index.php without specifying it in the URL.

Comment: True its default by Apache and its also work for `http://www.example.com/` main domain but maybe its not true for your subdomain.

Comment: @RahilWazir then why would the `.htacces` ModRewrite and ErrorDocuments getting picked up ín the subdomain? I'd be willing to try it, but I highly doubt it would make a change.

Comment: Because The condition `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` failed or the `RewriteRule` failed to match any request uri.

Answer (score 0):

Your rule looks fine to me.

On the other hand, you probably need this in an `.htaccess` file inside your `login` folder:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

I am guessing that you get a `404` with `http://login.example.com/` because it is looking for a default `index.html` that does not exist. Apache needs to be told to use `index.php` as the index file for that folder.

Comment: I have added a `.htaccess` file in the `login` folder, with
    DirectoryIndex index.php inside of it but it still doesn't work! I have also added an `index.html` file in the `login` folder, but when I go to `http://login.example.com/` now it gives me a 500-error. Could I maybe somehow exclude the `login` folder from the default `.htaccess` file in the document root?